# Find and traverse each section in a file?

Tags: python, regex

I read a file line by line and divided into sections by the occurrence of the word "-U-:Sent" using python. Now for each of the sections, I have written a set of regex expressions to extract certain data. I am trying to find and read through each section one by one and print the data for that section. However I am not getting any output.

Part of my file is as below:

```
LOAD: -U-: Sent: ID101 USD50000 None  
LOAD: ............data................  
LOAD: -U-: Sent: ID202 RUP30000 124ui  
LOAD:.............data...............
```

Such that each section is as follows:

```
LOAD: -U-: Sent: ID101 USD50000 None  
LOAD: ............data................  (till here)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
block=0
with open("file.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       if '-U-:Sent' in line:                #creating blocks or sections
          block+=1
          print("--------Block"+str(block)+"-------") 
       print(line)
       for l in line.splitlines():           #to go through each section
           m=re.findall(r'--------Block', l) #find sections and then read through them
           if m:
              #regex operation lines (same for all sections)
```

I expect to find each section and then do the regex extractions for each:

```
-------Block------  
{'ID':'101', 'Currency' : 'USD'}
```

(the extraction code has been written I just need to find each block and run the extraction code through each) but the actual output is coming empty. How can I change the code to get the desired output?

Comment: can you please specify your expected output with text input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read the whole file in a single string using `file.read()` and then clean it using python `re` module and string `split()` and `strip()` methods to directly get a list of the required data.

Try this out :

```
import re
with open("your_file_name") as file:
    blocks = [re.sub('LOAD.*','',section).strip(" \n\n") for section in file.read().split("LOAD: -U-: Sent:")][1:]
print(blocks)
```

**Output**

```
['ID101 USD50000 None', 'ID202 RUP30000 124ui']
```